# is there a way to pass unknown amount of types to generic method in C#?

Tags: c#, generics, generic-programming

I have a method

```
void InitAndLoadTables(DbConnection cnctn, Dictionary<string, DbTableLoadParameters> tableNamesAndParameters)
```

where dictionary can have any amount of tables. Every table corresponds a class.

When I iterate through all the tables I would like to call generic method

```
public void Init<T>(string tableName)
```

for all the tables. I tried to include type of the class to be property of DbTableLoadParameters as

```
Type ObjectType { get; set; }
```

and use that when calling Init. This does not work. So is it even possible to do? If the amount of tables would be fixed I could maybe make InitAndLoadTables generic like

```
InitAndLoadTables<T, K, V>
```

but it isn't. So is only possibility to call Init elsewhere like

```
Init<Orders>("Orders");
```

Thanks & BR -Matti

Comment: I don't think there is, it's very likely you'll have to pass an array/collection of `Type` objects (or `string`s with their names) instead.  Only posting as a comment in case there's something someone else can suggest

Comment: thanks for your answer, but what you mean "it's very likely you'll have to pass an array/collection of Type objects (or strings with their names) instead"?   that's exactly what I'm trying to do! but it doesn't work. What I know is that you can't pass Type object or string object that's value is type name to an generic method.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no way to pass an arbitrary number of type arguments to a generic method, because a generic method always has a fixed number of type arguments.

However, you don't even seem to need that. There is a way to call a generic method with a runtime-known type, but this involves reflection, which sounds like it's what you're *really* after:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var myobj = new MyClass();

        // Call MyClass.Init<Orders>
        CallMyClassInit(typeof(Orders), "tableOrders");

        // Call Init<string>
        CallMyClassInit(typeof(string), "tableString");
    }

    static void CallMyClassInit(MyClass obj, Type type, string tableName)
    {
        typeof(MyClass)
            .GetMethod("Init")
            .MakeGenericMethod(type)
            .Invoke(obj, new object[] { tableName });
    }
}

class Orders { }

class MyClass
{
    public void Init<T>(string tableName)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("I was called with type " + typeof(T) + " for table " + tableName);
    }
}
```

Output:

```
I was called with type ConsoleApplication1.Orders for table tableOrders
I was called with type System.String for table tableString
```

Comment: thanks a lot! this is what i was feared of ;) try it in a bit and accept if it works. thanks again!